# Java returning my chosen longest word, but returning the first word in the list and not the last

Tags: java

Class with parameter:

```
public class TestingLong{                                                                       
  public static String longTest(String s){                                                                          
    String[] longW = s.split(" ");                                      
    String t=" ";                                       

    for(int i=0; i<longW.length; i++){                                      
      if(longW[i].length()>=t.length()){                                        
        t=longW[i];                                     
      }                                     
    }                                                                       
    return t;                                       
  }                                     
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args){                                                                                                                                                   
    System.out.println(TestingLong.longTest("Dogs are just amazing things"));                                                                           
    System.out.println(TestingLong.longTest("Many cats hate dogs who live to bark"));                                       
  }                                     
}
```

I am writing a code where the longest word is returned, which it does, however, I am in confusion to why on the second statement containing many 4 letter words ("many cats hate dogs who live to bark"), the last word "bark" is returned and not the first word "many". How would I be able to return the first word?

Output:

```
Amazing
Bark
```

Comment: Change `>=` to `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am in confusion to why on the second statement containing many 4 letter words ("many cats hate dogs who live to bark"), the last word "bark" is returned and not the first word "many"

Because in the `if` statement you specify if the length is more than *or equal* `t` will be overridden by `longW[i]`:

```
if(longW[i].length()>=t.length()){                                        
    t=longW[i];                                     
}
```

To fix this only do more than:

```
if(longW[i].length()>t.length()){                                        
    t=longW[i];                                     
}
```